# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??=' at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16) - NodeJs

Tags: node.js, next.js, server

I am trying to delpoy next.js app with custom server configuration on shared hosting. I am getting "Error 503. Service Unavailable" error and SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??=' in my server logs. Only available node version on my server is 14.21.2.

server.js :

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')
 
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const hostname = 'localhost'
const port = 3000
// when using middleware `hostname` and `port` must be provided below
const app = next({ dev, hostname, port })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()
 
app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
      // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
      const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
      const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl
 
      if (pathname === '/a') {
        await app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
      } else if (pathname === '/b') {
        await app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
      } else {
        await handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error occurred handling', req.url, err)
      res.statusCode = 500
      res.end('internal server error')
    }
  })
    .once('error', (err) => {
      console.error(err)
      process.exit(1)
    })
    .listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`)
    })
})
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "white-homes-nekretnine",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "next lint",
    "lint-fix": "next lint --fix",
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@egjs/react-grid": "^1.12.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.6",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "apexcharts": "^3.35.5",
    "availity-reactstrap-validation": "^2.7.1",
    "axios": "^1.1.2",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "i18next": "^23.1.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.3",
    "lord-icon-element": "^3.4.4",
    "lottie-web": "^5.11.0",
    "next": "^13.0.3",
    "next-i18next": "^12.1.0",
    "next-pwa": "^5.6.0",
    "next-translate-routes": "^1.10.2",
    "photoswipe": "^5.3.2",
    "pigeon-maps": "^0.21.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-alert": "^7.0.3",
    "react-alert-template-basic": "^1.0.2",
    "react-alert-template-mui": "^1.0.7",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.0",
    "react-awesome-reveal": "^4.1.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.2",
    "react-content-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "react-data-table-component": "^7.5.3",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dropzone-uploader": "^2.11.0",
    "react-feather": "^2.0.10",
    "react-i18next": "^13.0.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.1.0",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^5.3.4",
    "react-photoswipe-gallery": "^2.2.2",
    "react-range": "^1.8.14",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "react-toastify": "^9.0.8",
    "reactstrap": "^9.1.4",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "swiper": "^8.4.3",
    "typed.js": "^2.0.12",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.25.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.0.3",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "os": false,
    "path": false
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  }
}
```

When I tried to open my web app it says "error 503 service unavailable and I get this error in server log.

Answer (score 0):

It's a node issue. I had same issues while using Next v13.4.x and Next13.3.x. I decided to downgrade it to Next v13.2.x.

> Most shared server can't go beyond 14.21.x unless you upgrade to VPS.

Kindly check this - https://github.com/HashLips/hashlips_art_engine/issues/424